# Trouble printing context in Django Cookiecutter template

Tags: django

**Background:**

- Django Cookiecutter template
- psql db
- Have created a new app and installed it per settings.py file

**What I want** = data from db to flow into the template view

**Problem:** No matter what I try I can't get the data visible in the template view on my local host.

**Views.py file** ('`<projectslug>/<projectslug>/appname/views.py`)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def exercise_table(request):
    var_dict = {
        'var_1': "wario",
        'var_2': snakes}
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context=var_dict)
```

**Template file** (`<projectslug>/<projectslug>templates/pages/home.html`)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <p>You are on home pg</p>
        <p>the name is: {{ var_1 }} wa ha ha</p>
        <p>the second var is: {{ var_2 }} stretch </p>
      </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Settings file (base.py)**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent
APPS_DIR = BASE_DIR / "projectslug"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#dirs
        "DIRS": [str(APPS_DIR / "templates")],
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#app-dirs
        "APP_DIRS": True,
}
```

All of the text in home.html displays as expected. The problem is accessing the variables within `{{ }}` brackets. No matter what I try the variables just do not appear.

I've cut down the system as it used to pull info from a psql db and populate in a complex table, but have been able to isolate it to the above issue.

Have tried remediating the path to the template in the `views.py` file for things like `../pages/home.html` & `../../pages/home.html` but doesn't change.

Also setting App_dirs = False does in settings.py also doesn't alter results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIL that Django can create template inheritance even without using the `{% extends "base.html" %}` tag.

I was able to successfully use the Django Debug Toolbar to identify the template inheritance back to the `base.html` file which was overriding all my template data.

For anyone in this position in future:

1. Start out with printing a basic `HttpResponse` and remove everything else from the template page (not just comment out, actually delete it or Django Debug Toolbar won't notice).
2. If successful, start adding back in the capability to extend base pages. You should be able to track this via the debug toolbar and identify your problem.